# ReportViewer Control Is not Visible in the Toolbox visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I did try again and again to add ReportViewer control into the toolbox.

I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your Visual Studio:
[image: This image explains how do it.] 
After this you can see ReportViewer in your Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you have managed and performed the following steps:

Open Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features, and select the entry for your version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. In our case, it was Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.
Click the "Change" button on the top bar above the program list.
After the splash screen, a window will open. Press the "Modify" button.
Select Windows and Web Development > Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, and check the box next to it.
Press the "Update" button on the lower-right hand side of the window.
Once the installation is complete, open your version of Visual Studio. After the new .dll files are loaded, Reporting functionality should be reimplemented, and you should be able to access all related forms, controls, and objects.

If you have installed:

1. Microsoft.ReportViewer.VS2015.WinForms
2. Microsoft.ReportViewer.VS2015.WebForms
   3  Microsoft.ReportViewer.2015.Runtime
3. Microsof report viewer 2015 (from Manage Nuget Packeges for Solution or get it here
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496)

And agian you are unable to create a report, Try the following step:

Launch Visual Studio. In form design mode go to the controls toolbox and Right click on it.
After select "Choose Items..."

After > click on browse and choose element in

*C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91*

Answer (score 0):

I do not think VS 2015 ships bundled with the control. get it here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from the link below:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in visual studio 2015. Right click on solution explorer & select Manage NuGet packages for solution and search for Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.VS2015.WinForms and install it. After installation add namespace in your .xaml page xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms". Drag & drop WindowsFormsHost control onto the .xaml page. And add following in your .xaml page

```
     <Grid>
         <WindowsFormsHost>
             <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="_reportViewer"/>
         </WindowsFormsHost>
     </Grid>
```

Comment: Let me know if your required any help.